# Warum haben Status und Modus einen unterschiedlichen Plural?

Tags: etymology

Laut Duden.de ist der Plural von Status ebenfalls Status (mit langem U ausgesprochen), während der Plural von Modus Modi ist.
Warum ist dies so?

Comment: Weil es im Lateinischen genauso war. Warum die Römer es so taten, ist wahrscheinlich nicht mehr zu ermitteln; warum *wir* sklavisch an ihren Flektierungen festhalten ist eine ganz andere, viel interessantere Frage (Linguistendünkel? Trägheit gegen Veränderung? Nützlichkeit für Altsprachler?)

Comment: Related, although not necessarily a duplicate: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/declension-of-latin-nouns-or-phrases-in-german

Comment: @KilianFoth: Ich denke, die Deklinationsklassen des Lateinischen sind recht gut verstanden: *Modus* gehört zur o-Deklination, das *u* der Endung war mal ein *o*, das in der letzten Silbe zu einem *u* wurde. *Status* gehört zur *u*-Deklination, wie viele andere substantivierte Verbalableitungen auch. Man könnte sagen: *Status* enthält ein "echtes" *u*, *Modus* nur ein *o*, das sloppy ausgesprochen und zu einem *u* wurde.

Comment: Außerdem war, wenn ich mich recht erinnere, die Endung des Plurals der u-Deklination ursprünglich _-uis_, das dann zu _-ūs_ wurde.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Im Deutschen besteht eine gewisse (aber meiner Beobachtung nach, sinkende) Tendenz dazu, bei Fremdwörtern die Pluralformen der Originalsprache zu übernehmen.

Nun hat Latein die Eigenschaft, dass zwei Wörter trotz gleicher Endung im Nominativ Singular eine unterschiedliche Endung im Nominativ Plural haben können. Dies ist vergleichbar mit dem Deutschen:

> *Frau – Frauen*
>   *Sau – Säue*
>   *Bau – Baue* oder *Bauten*
>   *Stau – Staus* oder *Staue*

Und im Lateinischen sind die Plurale nun mal:

> *status – statūs* (u-Deklination)
>   *modus – modi* (o-Deklination, Maskulinum)

und, zu allem Überfluss:

> *corpus – corpora* (konsonantische Deklination, Neutrum)

Mein Lieblingsbeispiel sind *Kasus, Numerus, Genus,* deren Plurale *Kasūs, Numeri, Genera* sind.

Früher war es übrigens üblich, nicht nur die Nominativformen für Singular und Plural zu übernehmen und alles Weitere unverändert zu lassen, sondern auch die Endungen für die Fälle zu übernehmen. Die findet sich heute noch ab und zu im kirchlichen Kontext, z. B. wird in *Mariä Empfängnis* der lateinische Genitiv von *Maria* verwendet.