# Plural von Nexus

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

Auf diversen Seiten (Bsp.: [Wiktionary – nexus](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nexus)) habe ich als Plural von Nexus die unveränderte Form *Nexus* gefunden.

Kann mir jemand sagen, wieso das so ist? Das Wort ist offensichtlich vom lateinischen *nexus* übernommen, wo der Plural *nexi* wäre, oder irre ich mich hier? Verwunderlich ist auch, dass ich nirgends *Nexi* als deutschen Plural gesehen habe, was mir auch nicht hundertprozentig falsch erscheint.

Comment: Wenn ich mit dem lat. Plural bereits falsch liege, wäre das womöglich eine Frage für das Lateinische Pendant der Seite.

Comment: Mögliches Duplikat von [Warum haben Status und Modus einen unterschiedlichen Plural?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20388/2594)

Comment: u-Deklination? Der Plural von *nexus* ist *nexūs*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das lateinische *nexus* ist nicht aus der verbreiteten a/o-Deklination, sondern der etwas selteneren u-Deklination, der Plural ist dann *nexus* (langes u) statt des nichtexistenten *nexi**.

*Nexi** wäre im Deutschen vielleicht zu *Nexen** eingedeutscht worden. Plurale der u-Deklination scheinen aber resistenter zu sein, zumal das Wort nicht sonderlich häufig auftritt.

Answer (score 7):

Es gibt im Lateinischen mindestens zwei Deklinationen, die im Nominativ Singular auf *-us* enden. Diejenige, die den Plural auf *-i* bildet, hat diese Endung auch im Genitiv.

Nexus gehört nicht dazu, siehe [Georges](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/nexus?hl=nexus) und [hier](http://www.latein-imperium.de/include.php?path=content&type=&contentid=14).

Answer (score 5):

**Nexus** und **Status** sind beides Wörter, die in der Originalsprache (Latein) im Nominativ im Singular und im Plural identisch sind.

Normalerweise muss man keine Fremdsprachen-Grammatik lernen wenn man Fremdwörter in einem deutschen Satz verwendet. Niemand muss Suaheli lernen, wenn er von seinen *Safaris* erzählt, oder Japanisch, um das Aussehen eines *Kimonos* zu beschreiben.

Latein ist in dieser Hinsicht eine Ausnahme, was darauf zurückzuführen ist, dass Latein als Sprache der Gelehrten galt, und man die lateinische Grammatik für hochwertiger ansah als die Grammatik der eigenen Muttersprache. Insbesondere bei Nomen der lateinischen a/o-Deklination hat sich das i als Plural- oder Genitiv-Endung durchgesetzt. Und das sogar bei Wörter, die gar nicht lateinischen Ursprungs sind, aber oft in einem lateinischen Kontext verwendet wurden:

> Christus (abgeleitet vom griechischen Χριστός Christos »der Gesalbte«)
>   »Der Leib *Christ**i***«

Die genannten Beispiele **Nexus** und **Status** enden zwar wie *Christus* auf -us, gehören aber nicht zur a/o-Deklination, sondern zur u-Deklination.

Übernimmt man die lateinischen Deklinations-Endungen ins Deutsche, erhält man:

Nominativ Singular:

> Der Status dieses Projekts ist ungewiss.
>   Der Nexus ist verschwunden.

Nominativ Plural:

> Die Status aller Projekte sind ungewiss.
>   Die Nexus sind verschwunden.

Nun ist in Wahrheit aber die lateinische Grammatik, wie jede andere Fremdsprachen-Grammatik, für deutsche Sätze völlig irrelevant. Es interessiert ja auch niemanden, dass der Plural der italienischen »Pizza« eigentlich »pizze« ist. Und so haben sich für dieses Wort auch zwei deutsche Pluralformen entwickelt, die beide gleichberechtigt sind: »Pizzen« und »Pizzas«.

Im Fall von **Nexus** und **Status** ist es gegenwärtig so, dass die aus dem Lateinischen stammenden Pluralformen »*(die vielen) **Nexus***« und »*(die vielen) **Status***« als gültige deutsche Formen gelten, und dass es daneben noch die alternativen Form »*(die vielen) **Statusse***« gibt, nicht aber »<del>*(die vielen) **Nexusse***</del>«.

Es ist also auch erlaubt: 
Nominativ Plural:

> Die Statusse aller Projekte sind ungewiss.

Falsch ist hingegen:

> <del>Die Nexusse sind verschwunden.</del>

Auch das ist ausdrücklich falsch:

> <del>Die Stati aller Projekte sind ungewiss.</del>
>   <del>Die Nexi sind verschwunden.</del>

Comment: nexus (Singular) und nexūs (Plural) sind nicht identisch.

Comment: @fdb: Die Transkriptionen ins Deutsche sind schon identisch, denn *ū* ist kein Zeichen, das im deutschen Standardalphabet vorkommt, bzw. ist das Makron kein diakritisches Zeichen, das im Deutschen Verwendung findet, weswegen es beim Transkribieren von Fremdsprachen ins Deutsche weggelassen wird.

Comment: Du hast geschrieben: "Wörter, die in der Originalsprache (Latein) im Nominativ im Singular und im Plural identisch sind." Das ist falsch. In Latein sind sie nicht identisch.